# Ubuntu Wacom touch mode

Tags: wacom

Can i actually turn off touch mode in Ubuntu 18.04.3?
My current Wacom is Intuos 5 touch s pth-450.
Was trying to disable it in Tweak mode and also in dconf editor.
So far i still have touch mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04.3 does not offer a graphical control for disabling touch on these kinds of tablets. It is, however, possible to disable touch through xsetwacom or with a custom xorg.conf.d configuration.

#### xsetwacom

You can use the `xsetwacom` command to immediately enable or disable touch. The setting will only persist for your current login session. See `man xsetwacom` for more details.

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos5 touch S Finger touch" touch off
```

#### xorg.conf.d

You can use an xorg.conf.d file to change the default touch setting for your tablet. See `man wacom` and `man xorg.conf.d` for more details. The following snippet should be saved as a file inside the xorg.conf.d directory (e.g. `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-wacom-touchpad.conf`)

```
# Disable touch on all Wacom touchpads by default.
# https://askubuntu.com/a/1190357/736425

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom Touchpad Disable"
    MatchDriver "wacom"
    MatchIsTouchpad "true"
    Option "Touch" "off"
EndSection
```

Comment: Can i add interface that i have on kde enviroment were i can disable touch mode with a shortcut or change screen mapping?

Comment: Also could someone tell me how can i make a command that plays "xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos5 touch S Finger touch" touch off if already off plays xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos5 touch S Finger touch" touch on othewise it plays xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos5 touch S Finger touch" touch off" . So i could add it as a keyboard shortcut ?

Comment: One-liner:

`ID="Wacom Intuos5 touch S Finger touch"; NEWSTATE=$(xsetwacom get "$ID" touch | sed 's/off/1/; s/on/0/; s/0/off/; s/1/on/'); echo "Turning touch $NEWSTATE"; xsetwacom set "$ID" touch $NEWSTATE`