Disable touchscreen on ASUS zenbook
The touchscreen on my ASUS Zenbook UX370UA goes crazy quite frequently, causing the mouse to jump around. It's 4 years old and I rarely use the touchscreen so I figure it's easiest to disable it.
I cannot see any option to do that in the settings or even the BIOS.
Following other methods to disable it, I have discovered that it might be a Wacom touchscreen due to the presence of /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wacom.conf
There it mentions 'touchscreen' as well as 'touchpad' and 'tablet'. Following other advice, I added this to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-wacom-touchscreen.conf
adam@erebor:~$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-wacom-touchscreen.conf
# Disable touch on all Wacom touchpads by default.
# https://askubuntu.com/a/1190357/736425

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom Touchscreen Disable"
    MatchDriver "wacom"
    MatchIsTouchscreen "true"
    Option "Touch" "off"
EndSection

But my touchscreen is as alive as before.
Any advice?
[EDIT] Running Linux Mint 21.3 with Cinnamon. That is Ubuntu 22.04

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; your chosen solution uses X.org config which may do nothing if your machine isn't using X.org (you've provided no specifics as to your install so we cannot know)

@guiverc Oh I see. It's Mint, not vanilla Ubuntu, and the Mint discussion board is currently down.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)

Don't forget Linux Mint has an additional layer of software that Ubuntu does not include (the runtime adjustments that allow them to use foreign Ubuntu packages). Ubuntu upgrades make no allowance for them, which means some adjustments need tweaking after security patches flow through from Ubuntu - these are usually evident on screen; but you're off-topic asking about those here; as Ubuntu & flavors all have write access to Ubuntu repositories, thus they don't use runtime adjustments; Linux Mint differs in many ways

Debian does not include touch screen drivers by default. If you want to stick to mint, try LMDE

Try Ubuntu 24.04. The touchscreen support may have improved
